# Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ',',')'. Incorrect syntax near ',',')'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp

Me pueden ayudar ha corregir este detalle por favor

```
       public void crear(Alumno objAlumno)
    {
        string crear = "insert into Persona(idAlumno,nombre,Apellido,Telefono)values('" + objAlumno.IdAlumno + "'," + objAlumno.Nombre + "','" + objAlumno.Apellido1 + "','" + objAlumno.Telefono1 + "')";
        try
        {
            conn = new SqlCommand(crear, objConexion.getcon());
            objConexion.getcon().Open();
            conn.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            objConexion.getcon().Close();
            objConexion.cerrarConexion();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Te falta una comilla aqui: `objAlumno.IdAlumno + "',"`

Comment: Gracias amigo ya lo corregi Otra cosa me sale otro error que es el siguiente
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Persona' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

create table Persona(IdAlumno int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, Nombre varchar(50),Apellido varchar(50),Telefono varchar(50), Estado  int)

Comment: Dice que no puedes insertar valores en la columna `idAlumno` porque se genera automaticamente.

Comment: @alanfcm ya lo corregí ahora ya puedo insertar pero no en la BD los inserta pero no aparece el apellido y teléfono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo te que falta una comilla simple despues de `objAlumno.IdAlumno + "',`
quedaria así:

```
    string crear = "insert into Persona(idAlumno,nombre,Apellido,Telefono)values('" + objAlumno.IdAlumno + "','" + objAlumno.Nombre + "','" + objAlumno.Apellido1 + "','" + objAlumno.Telefono1 + "')";
```

Ya me contaras ;) un saludo!